# BeautifulSoup is not reading the section tags as expected

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Testing with getting data from, edition.cnn.com/?refresh=1

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen

my_url = urlopen("http://edition.cnn.com/?refresh=1")

sauce = my_url.read()

soup = soup(sauce,"lxml")

my_div = soup.find("div",{"class":"pg-no-rail"})

my_sections = my_div.findAll("section")

for section in my_sections:
    print(section)

my_url.close()
```

but it reads it like:

```
<section class="zn--idx-0 zn-empty"> </section>
<section class="zn--idx-1 zn-empty"> </section>
<section class="zn--idx-2 zn-empty"> </section>
<section class="zn--idx-3 zn-empty"> </section>
<section class="zn--idx-4 zn-empty"> </section>
<section class="zn--idx-5 zn-empty"> </section>
<section class="zn--idx-6 zn-empty"> </section>
<section class="zn--idx-7 zn-empty"> </section>
```

I want to reach the h2 element highlighted in the image
[image: image of the inspector]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element you are trying to fetch does not exist in on the original page, instead it is created using javascript. If you look at the source of the page (right click and choose "View Soruce" or similair) and you will not be able to find it.

The way i see it, you have three options, where number three probably fits your needs the best:

**1 (Execute the javascript):** To be able to parse the things you want, you need to load the page in a real browser which can execute the javascript. One way to do this in python by using [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/index.html). See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36225844/how-can-i-parse-a-dynamic-page-using-python) for reference. When you have executed the Javascript, you can parse the page and find the element you are looking for.

**2 (Parse the javascript):** Or you can try to parse the javascript on the page, where you can find the headline:

[image]

To do this you probably want to use regexp, and not BeautifulSoup

**3 (Parse the RSS-feed):** But the Best option is probably to parse their RSS-feed instead, using this url:
http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition.rss (or any other URL found on http://edition.cnn.com/services/rss/)