# IndexError by using Xpath for scraping

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, algorithmic-trading

I created this code in order to get real time amazon index market data from the platform PLUS 500:

```
import requests
import bs4
from lxml import etree
from Config import username, password

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "Connection": "keep-alive"
}

with requests.session() as session:
    url = 'https://app.plus500.com/trade/amazon'
    page = requests.get(url, auth=(username, password), headers=headers)
    try:
        page.raise_for_status()
    except Exception as exc:
        print(f'Problem: {exc}')
    html_page = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    print(html_page.prettify())
    dom = etree.HTML(str(html_page))
    print(dom.xpath('//*[@id="_win_plus500_bind818"]')[0].text)
```

I created a dummy account for you in case it is necessary Username: myrandomcode@gmail.com Password: MyRandomCode87

the problem I get back is this one

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "############", line 24, in <module>
    print(dom.xpath('//*[@id="_win_plus500_bind818"]')[0].text)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I am trying to scrape the sell and buy prices.

Comment: Hello, Emasei, I hope you were able to solve the problem with the answer I provided. If so, I would be very grateful if you could mark it as 'accepted', thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting is related to the indexing operation `[0].text`.

Make sure the element you're trying to access exists. Also, make sure the `@id` you're using doesn't change when you refresh the web page (`"_win_plus500_bind818"`).

Answer (score 0):

The page you are trying to parse is dynamic, meaning the content is loaded after loading the page itself. To parse the dynamic page, you have to use `selenium`, for example.

More details you can find in the following answer:
[How can I parse a dynamic page using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36225844/how-can-i-parse-a-dynamic-page-using-python)